# mounting a solaris partition in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, solaris

I have task to search old external harddrives for a specific file. The drives were used with a Sun Ultrasparc 1, so they are pretty old. I have 4 drives, and I managed to mount one of them in a Sun which uses Solaris 9. I cannot mount the other ones because this was the only case were my cables fit. So I found an SCSI controller and put it into my linux machine (Ubuntu 10.10) and connected the drive. I used the one drive I had access to, because I backuped everything and I know it did work.

Now, the problem is, that I cannot mount it in ubuntu. using {fdisk -l} I get

Festplatte /dev/sdc („Sun disklabel“): 30 Köpfe, 91 Sektoren, 2878 Zylinder
Einheiten: Zylinder mit 2730 × 512 Byte

Gerät Flag    Start       Ende   Blöcke   Id  System

/dev/sdc1             0      2878   3928470    0  Unassigned
/dev/sdc3             0      2878   3928470    0  Unassigned

Festplatte /dev/sdc1 („Sun disklabel“): 30 Köpfe, 91 Sektoren, 2878 Zylinder
Einheiten: Zylinder mit 2730 × 512 Byte

Gerät Flag    Start       Ende   Blöcke   Id  System

/dev/sdc1p1             0      2878   3928470    0  Unassigned
/dev/sdc1p3             0      2878   3928470    0  Unassigned

Festplatte /dev/sdc3 („Sun disklabel“): 30 Köpfe, 91 Sektoren, 2878 Zylinder
Einheiten: Zylinder mit 2730 × 512 Byte

Gerät Flag    Start       Ende   Blöcke   Id  System

/dev/sdc3p1             0      2878   3928470    0  Unassigned
/dev/sdc3p3             0      2878   3928470    0  Unassigned}

I think the main problem here is "Unassigned".

If I use dmesg | grep sdc I get[    5.842160] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk....ready
[   10.254764] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] 7866080 512-byte logical blocks: (4.02 GB/3.75 GiB)
[   10.257375] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[   10.257381] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 8f 00 10 08
[   10.262421] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
[   10.273597]  sdc: sdc1 sdc3
[   10.468921] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk

This is the right disk...

Any Ideas how to mount in properly?
Thx.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, I finally found the command to do it. In case somebody wants to know:

mount -oufstype=sunx86 -o ro

works very good.

Comment: That's odd. As you created your disk on a UltraSPARC 1, that should have been -o ufstype=sun (UFS big endian), not ufstype=sunx86 which is for filesystems created on a x86 machine, i.e. little endian UFS. Perhaps the mount command is smart enough to detect the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that the default kernel in Ubuntu supports the Sun disk layout.

I would suggest getting an OpenSolaris Live CD and boot on it on your PC.  Hopefully it will recognize and mount the drive.

Comment: Unfortunately, unlike Linux, Solaris doesn't support cross architecture mounts with UFS.

Comment: Hi,

I tried this, but neither my laptop nor my linux machine can read or boot from the opensolaris boot cd.

Comment: @arpad, there is two architectures, intel and Sparc.  You need the correct one.

Comment: @jliagre, I didn't know that.